# associate posts to a page

Tags: posts, pages

I created a theme, and I created a page for the theme, and now I want to associate posts to the page. I read this article:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

Look under the section "Examples of Pages and Templates", there is this code:

```
<div id="content" class="widecolumn">
 <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
 <div class="post">
 <h2 id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></h2>
 <div class="entrytext">
  <?php the_content('<p class="serif">Read the rest of this page &raquo;</p>'); ?>
 </div>
 </div>
 <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

It seems to be pulling some posts associated with a page. How can I create posts for a page? And if not possible, what are they doing or what kind of altenrative is available to me, other than hardcoding html into the page?

Comment: A page _is_ a post, with the 'post type' of 'page'. If you're referring to this code: `<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>` -- This is '[The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)'.

Comment: @Jared my question though is I want posts on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wp_query` with different arguments to list the posts that you want to appear on that specific page (i.e. all the post that are assigned to the X category or all the post that belong to Y author a.s.o). You can find on the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) a detailed presentation and examples on how to use wp_query.

Comment: Hey great, Ill check it out. I honestly, think its just easier when I come to think of it, just use the page box to add the content, but your suggestion Ill keep in mind.